# ElasticSearch NEST searchresponse.hits data not populated

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-webapi, nest

I have an index in ElasticSearch. I have setup an ASP.NET core lambda serverless app. I inject IElasticClient into my controller.

I want my controller to be signed as `public IEnumerable<StreamSummary> Get()` and the ElasticSearch query I would have thought to be as as simple as return `searchResponse.Hits.Select(h => h.Source).ToList();` but this is not the case as can be seen below.

I query my Index with something basic like this

```
var searchResponse = elasticClient.Search<StreamSummary>(s => s
                .Index("myindex")
                .Query(q => q.MatchAll()
                )
            );
```

When I log how many "hits" I get, it is the correct amount (`searchResponse.Hits.Count`).

When I set my controller  return `IEnumerable<StreamSummary>` and use `searchResponse.Hits.Select(h => h.Source).ToList()` the list is the correct number but every entry has no values. `DateTime` fields are all `Datetime.Min` strings are empty, nullables are `null`. It's basically an empty/freshly instantiated class and not populated/serialised as I would have expected it to be.

When I iterate the hits and display/log Index,Type and Id, this all works and displays exactly as I expect. The Issue I am having is with _source (Source Property NEST).

```
foreach (var searchResponseHit in searchResponse.Hits)
                    {
                        hits.Add(searchResponseHit.Index);
                        hits.Add(searchResponseHit.Type);
                        hits.Add(searchResponseHit.Id); searchResponseHit.Source
                    searchResponseHit.Source // here is the problem, no populated StreamSummary data}
```

Where hits is `List<string> hits = new List<string>();`

So I dig a bit further and in my `Startup.cs` I `DisableDirectStreaming()` on `ConnectionSettings()` so I can get at the request/response buffered byte streams.

I then do the following:

```
var requestJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
                    var responseJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);
                    return searchResponse.ApiCall.HttpMethod.ToString() + searchResponse.ApiCall.Uri + "\n" + requestJson + "\r\n" + responseJson;
```

This is an inccomplete/part response but as you can see it contains a lot of escape characters etc. (Could this be part of the problem, a serialisation issue??)

```
\"hits\" : {\n    \"total\" : {\n      \"value\" : 9,\n      \"relation\" : \"eq\"\n    },\n    \"max_score\" : 1.0,\n    \"hits\" : [\n      {\n        \"_index\" : \"accounts\",\n        \"_type\" : \"_doc\",\n        \"_id\" : \"U3P 1 8fb4b770-4e29-4f0d-aec8-1bcd4199005f\",\n        \"_score\" : 1.0,\n        \"_source\" : {\n          \"ProcessingResponse\" : \"Success\",\n          \"ProviderId\" : 6,\n
```

Connection/Client:

```
 var uri = new Uri(Configuration["ElasticSearch:Url"]);
        var httpConnection = new AwsHttpConnection(new BasicAWSCredentials(Configuration["AWS:AwsAccessKeyId"], Configuration["AWS:AwsSecretAccessKey"]),
            RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(Configuration["ElasticSearch:Region"]));
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(uri);
        var config = new ConnectionSettings(pool, httpConnection).DefaultIndex(Startup.ElasticSearchIndex)
            .DisableDirectStreaming().PrettyJson();
        var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(config);
        services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(elasticClient);
```

POCO is:

```
public class StreamSummary : ResponseSummary
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int? ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string ProviderAccount { get; set; }
    public int? ProcessingTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProcessedTimeUtc { get; set; }
}
```

where Response Summary Contains a couple of nullable decimals(but also has an `IList<AnotherClass>`)

Help Appreciated.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: I'm not at the pc at the moment but it is the latest nuget package (7.5.1). Elasticsearch is the aws default. I'm sure it was 7 or 7.1

Comment: Did you create (index) your documents using this POCO or from another application (share mappings if this is the case). Can you give a try with only field from StreamSummary class (= without the parent ResponseSummay?, i suspect serialisation got issues with the IList at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is what you're after:

```
searchResponse.Documents
```

Comment: Apologies,  I also tried .Documents. It is symptomatic as above.

Comment: If you have a Kibana instance running on the cluster, I would log into it and try the query in the "Dev Tools" to see what Elasticsearch returns.

Comment: I have kibana setup and dev tools works without  issue. I took the requestjson above and dumped  it into kibana and it executed. But I had to trim all the escape characters.

Comment: `.Documents` is a convenient shortcut for `.Hits.Select(h => h.Source)`, so I would suspect it to reflect the same